# what is this yellow flower

Tags: identification, flowers

Yellow flower in bush, from the South of France[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is Phlomis fruticosa, commonly known as Jerusalem sage, simply because the leaves feel and look similar to sage - it is not commonly used for culinary purposes, though it is edible. It's a hardy shrub that likes full sun, is drought tolerant, and benefits from pruning back annually or biennially to prevent legginess at the base. It will grow successfully in poor soils, but really prefers fertile conditions. https://dorsetperennials.co.uk/product/phlomis-fruticosa/